# top and left in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have really problem adjusting the top and the left in IE6, in all the remaining browsers things are working good.

I have this css:

```
font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
height: 590px;
left: 50px;
line-height: normal;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
top: -42px;
width: 760px;
z-index: 0;
```

**EDIT**

This top and left I get it from javascript like that:

```
     function()
       {H(a,{left:0,top:0});g=a.getBoundingClientRect();H(a,{left:"50px",top:"-42px"})}
```

I don't have css file to put codes, so if I change top and hight its not triggered in IE6. 
Its like I am not doing nothing.

I wonder if IE6 don't handle top and left? How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, for IE6 to render rather correctly, *all* blocks on page should have `hasLayout` enabled. I usually (somewhen about up to 2 years ago) achieved that by using `height: 1px` either in personal IE6 stylesheet or with "star" hack:

```css
/* hasLayout is now on in IE6 for elements having `example` class. */
* HTML .example {height: 1px; }
```

But IE6 does not deserve *any* efforts currently (I don't support it at all as of 2011 and recommend everyone to do the same).

Comment: me too i have all IE but what can i do . my code is from javascript , i dont have css file to put this code.

Comment: I would humbly recommend to drop support of IE6. This can be elegantly achieved using [technique](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/universal_internet_explorer_6_css/) with independent simplified stylesheet based on HTML semantics.

Comment: Of the two people who still use IE6, I'm pretty sure one died.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:absolute` instead of `relative`. IE6 handles positioning usually very well. Not sure if you're using absolutely positioned children inside of this div though.

Edit.

If you're using conditionals. e.g.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>      <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
```

You can target the absolute positioning only in ie6.

```
.ie6 .your-selector {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Are you using html classes on a browser vendor basis? it'd be very simple to target ie6 only.

Comment: @peter Use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to add CSS just for IE 6.

Comment: im not using html , this css is coming from javascript not from css file. or inline or style ,